# Bash Shell script in unix to rsh to another machine and perform command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Im trying to write a script that rsh's over to a unix machine and executes certain commands on certain files

1. rsh's over to machine (in this case a machine called uk01ff200)
2. searches for a directory in machine
3. then within that directory searches for a files starting with core
4. executes a command on those files (if they exist) which then creates new files

SCRIPT SO FAR:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
MACHINE=uk01ff200
DIRECTORY=/var/core

rsh $MACHINE "cd /var/core"
for file in `ls -1 core.*`           
do stack_dump $file         
done
```

When I do this manually in the shell on the command line it works. So if I rsh over to the machine, cd to the directory, then type in the for loop it works (so I know the for loop syntax is correct). So I dont know where I'm going wrong with my script.

Comment: Non-interactively `rsh` does not start a shell for you. Those next lines are being run locally and not on the remote host. You need to make them part of the command argument to `rsh` itself.

Comment: @EtanReisner Could you show me how you would do that in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do using a [here-document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) :

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
MACHINE=uk01ff200
DIRECTORY=/var/core

rsh $MACHINE bash <<'EOF'
cd /var/core
for file in core.*          
    do stack_dump "$file"         
done
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Doesnt seem to be working though? When I run the script the shell returns:
`rlogin: closed connection.`

Is there anything missing from this script?

Comment: Have you tested my last edited snippet ? Did you check that stack_dump have been executed ?

Comment: I think this needs to be `rsh "$MACHINE" bash` or similar to run a shell to receive standard input or a single string as argument.

Comment: @sputnick just tried your last snippet! worked perfectly! Thanks!